# Understanding java.util.Scanner's effect on InputStream

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Hoping to get a clearer understanding of how Scanner's innards work...I've implemented what I need without Scanner, but am just trying to understand why this didn't work the way I thought it would.

Context: I'm writing a text parser that needs to regularly switch from reading lines of text (line mode) to reading a set number of bytes (byte mode) from the same input stream. Byte mode is entered if BYTE\n is seen in the input stream; an integer is expected to follow that specifies the number of bytes to read. Byte mode is exited when ENDBYTE\n is seen after a valid integer/byte sequence.

I tried using Scanner to implement this parser with a delimiter of "\n" to read in "line mode." I thought that if I switched the delimiter to the regex pattern of ".{1}" mid-stream, it would start to give me one byte at a time so that I could process data in "raw mode" (this was after a lot of wasted time tinkering with Scanner.nextByte() before I realized that method does not actually just give you the next byte in the InputStream).

I tried putting in this sequence into Scanner's InputStream:

```
BYTE\n32\nNegative, I am a meat popsicle.\nENDBYTE\n
```

As soon as I parse "32\n", I try changing the delimiter to ".{1}". If I then ask for next(), I get "\n", and then Scanner strangely reports that it has more tokens, but they turn out to be empty. If I leave the delimiter as "\n", I correctly get "Negative, I am a meat popsicle." as the next token.

So I'm assuming that either:

1. ".{1}" does not just match a single character as I intended...not sure why this would be though?
2. Scanner alters the InputStream by constantly reading as much as it can and preemptively parsing the data into tokens. I'm inclined to believe that this is true, since when I printed the results of available() calls on the InputStream, the number of available bytes goes to zero after my first call to next() with the delimiter set to "\n". This means changing the delimiter mid-processing is very confusing for Scanner, and it looks like it behaves erroneously as a result?

Any regex/Scanner expertise would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. I just ended up reading individual bytes myself out of the InputStream and looking for "\n" manually in line mode...not pretty, but works just the way I want.

Comment: Post the code relevant fragment

Answer (score 1):

The regex `".{1}"` (which by the way is identical to `"."`) does **not** match the newline character.

To match any character *including* the newline, turn on the "dot matches newline" switch in your regex:

```
(?s).
```

#### Edited

I would recommend *not* using a delimiter. Just consume the input like this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // do something with line
}
```

Comment: Hm well just based on that, it seems like Scanner would be a pretty crummy way to scan for arbitrary byte values anyway? That plus the fact that Scanner seems to clear its InputStream (which prevents me from telling Scanner to hold on and let me take a few bytes out before giving it back to it), makes this seem like a bad use case for Scanner. Please let me know if you disagree, thanks!

Comment: Don't use a delimiter: Just consume the input using its API. See edited answer

Comment: As far as I understood njhwang wants to read bytes in between special lines. But there is no guarantee that a Scanner does not buffer anything while reading from a stream. So reading from the wrapped InputStream after a line "BYTE" and a line with the length argument might start at some offset caused by buffering in Scanner.

Comment: Yes, @Ame has the right of it. Seems like we're in agreement that I cannot rely on Scanner to leave the wrapped InputStream intact for processing at the byte level at arbitrary times.